# How should tensorflow_probability distributions be used for multi-dimensional spaces?

Tags: python, tensorflow, probability-density, tensorflow-probability

I would like to create a multi-dimensional gaussian probability density function (let's say a 2D gaussian like in the figure below) with tensorflow.

[image]

For 1D, it works like a charm:

```
d = tfp.distributions.Normal(loc=5.0, scale=3.0)
x = d.prob(tf.range(0,10, dtype=tf.float32))
```

But for higher dimension, I get `InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes` error using `Normal` or `MultivariateNormalDiag` distributions... What do I miss? How should the `prob` method be used to output the probability density function on a multi dimensional tensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can do something like:

```
mu = [0,0]
cov = [[1,0],
       [0,1]]
mv_normal = np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, cov, size=1000)
mv_normal_mean = np.mean(mv_normal , axis=0)
mv_normal_cov = np.cov(mv_normal , rowvar=0)
mv_normal_diag = np.diag(mv_normal_cov)
mv_normal_stddev = np.sqrt(mv_normal_diag)
```

mv_normal is just like:

```
mv_normal
array([[-1.73476374,  0.17578855],
       [ 0.11866498, -0.66417069],
       [ 1.52000069, -1.3004096 ],
       ...,
       [-1.37625595, -0.46864374],
       [ 0.81659449,  0.70524036],
       [ 1.12183633,  0.14196896]])
```

`mv_normal_mean` and `mv_normal_cov` etc are just arrays here. They will be used to create:

```
 mvn = tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag(
 loc=mv_normal_mean,
 scale_diag=mv_normal_stddev)
```

Values can be seen as:

```
mvn_mean
array([-0.03976356,  0.07387231])
```

```
mv_normal_cov
array([[ 1.04138867, -0.00877481],
       [-0.00877481,  0.97736496]])
```

And you can use contour plot for plotting.

```
x1, x2 = np.meshgrid(mv_normal[:,0], mv_normal[:,1])
data = np.stack((x1.flatten(), x2.flatten()), axis=1)
prob = mvn.prob(data).numpy()
plt.figure(figsize = (12,9))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x1, x2, prob.reshape(x1.shape), cmap = 'Blues')
plt.show()
```

That will produce as follows:
[image]

Comment: thanks. Actually what I missed was the order of the channels that were wrong when I tested.